# GPS - Best way of calculating distance between many points

Tags: locationmanager, android-gps

I have a problem with my GPS on Android (provider is set to GPS!) and I do not know how to tackle it.

I am working on a running track app.
My current approach is to request location updates minTimesMs = 0, and minDistanceMeter = 10 meter.

```
requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTimeMs*1000, (float) minDistanceMeter, locationListener)
```

Then, I am putting the latitude and longitude coordinates into a list and calculate the distance between these points.
As a second action I compare the provided speed and a predefined min-speed.
If the delivered speed is greater than the min-speed (4.8), the distance between the last two recorded points will be calculated and summed up.

Now the problem is that my covered distance is adding up constantly although I have not moved that much.

Maybe, someone can tell me what else I should consider to get a better result of my covered path?

Side note: Accuracy is set to `ACCURACY_FINE and ACCURACY_HIGH.`

Here is my code

```
private void startLocationListener() {
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();

            //get the location name from latitude and longitude
            latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            polylinePoints.add(latLng);

            //get speed
            speed = (location.getSpeed()/1000)*3600;
            Log.d("SPEED", String.valueOf(location.getSpeed()));

            //number of satellites
            Log.d("NUMBER OF SATELLITES", String.valueOf(location.getExtras().getInt("satellites")));
        }
    };
}

private void calculateDistance() {
    LatLng penultimatelastEntry = polylinePoints.get(polylinePoints.size()-2);
    double startLat = penultimatelastEntry.latitude;
    double startLng = penultimatelastEntry.longitude;

    Double oldDoubleLat = startLat;
    Double oldDoubleLng = startLng;

    LatLng lastEntry = polylinePoints.get(polylinePoints.size()-1);
    double newDoubleLat = lastEntry.latitude;
    double newDoubleLng = lastEntry.longitude;

    if(speed>minimumSpeedLimit) {
        Location.distanceBetween(oldDoubleLat, oldDoubleLng, newDoubleLat, newDoubleLng, result);
        calc += result[0];
        saveToDatabase();
        sendBroadcastToMapsActivity(polylinePoints);
    }
}
```